# how do I add json object keys together using java?

Tags: java, json

For example, with the json object:

```
{
"name": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "analytics",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "cluster",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
      {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
      {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
      {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "graph",
     "children": [
      {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},
      {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},
      {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},
      {"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},
      {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "optimization",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AspectRatioBanker", "size": 7074}
     ]
    }
   ]
  }
}
```

How would I go about adding up the values (file sizes) for the child files and assigning it as a value for the parent folder? For example, in the above json object, assigning the sum of the child file sizes to "cluster" as the value, instead of 'children'.

Comment: Use a JSON handling library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can to use [Jackson Json processor Library](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDownload), with the library you can to map your Json in custom Java Object.

Comment: gson, https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/, is good too. you can use it to convert the JSON object into a Java object, manipulate it, and then convert it back to json.